# "REACT_APP_VERSION' is not recognized as an internal or external command" on windows

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

Hey everyone I'm on windows and i'm getting an error when trying to run my script
I'm getting this error

```
REACT_APP_VERSION' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

This is what i have on the script

```
"start:react": "REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version NODE_PATH=./src HTTPS=false react-scripts start"
```

But I'm new to this project so not sure how to solve this. I think it has something to do with environment variables, but I'm sort of new to coding so I have no point of reference.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Check [this](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#windows-cmdexe).

Comment: @Kiranvj No still didn't work, I was reading something about having to add something to the environment variables path but not sure what to add if that is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, I had to run a WSL and just run it through Linux. Something to do with Windows environment variables are not available globally.

But running the WSL it worked